# Responsive web design, html width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm trying to make my website responsive, if you go to my website [here](https://robertmakar.github.io/Second-Website/)
and go to dev tools and you toggle device toolbar and under responsive, if you resize the window under 900px width, you'll see that the html element(through the whole page) is shrinking to a size smaller that the actual width although I have my width set to 100%, any ideas how to fix this?

Here's the code if you want to check it out: [here](https://codepen.io/robertashraf/pen/GmELJZ)

```
    html{
      width: 100%;
      }


    body{
      width: 100%;
      }
```

Comment: Can you post your code in the question instead of asking people to click out to a link to see it

Comment: Should I post All of the code? I can't seem to find where's the problem exactly in the code or how to fix it

Comment: There's a mistake in your viewport declaration, you should change it to this - <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: remove width: 900px; of .name

Answer (score 1):

What will work is the following rule:

```
.navgiationbar ul  {
  width: 100vw;
}
```

But I'm sure there is a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen your website and found that more of section used width in pixel like that header h1 title. So every where use width in percent not pixel.

You can Write header code like that this and remove this class css ".name" and use my css:

```css
.header-title {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
}
.header-text {
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
.v-align {
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
.name {
 font-family: "Cookie";
 font-size: 100px;
 color: white;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-title">
  <div class="header-text">
    <div class="v-align">
      <h1 class="name">Robert A. Makar</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```